# Preventing Duplicate Documents in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have this schema:

```
const carStatusSchema = new Schema({
carColor: { type: String, required: true },
status: { type: String, required: true },
brand: { type: String, required: true }
})
```

And I use this code when I need to update my document or create new if it isn't exist:

```
const options = { upsert: true, new: true };
const filter = {
    carColor: req.body.carColor,
    brand: req.body.brand
};
const updateInfo = { status: req.body.status };

await carStatusSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateInfo, options, (err, result) => {
    if (err) { return console.log('Can\'t update data: ', err); }
    console.log('Updated data: ', result);
});
```

But sometimes, when I try to insert a new document, it gets duplicated.
For example, my collection has documents like this:

```
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'black', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'bmv'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'black', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'toyota'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'green', status: 'In Progress 01', brand: 'cherry'},
```

Very rare, but when I try to insert a similar document:

```
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'lightGreen', status: 'In Progress 02', brand: 'cherry'}
```

It finds no match for the update (as expected) and creates two identical documents:

```
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'black', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'bmv'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'black', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'toyota'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'green', status: 'In Progress 01', brand: 'cherry'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'lightGreen', status: 'In Progress 02', brand: 'cherry'},
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'lightGreen', status: 'In Progress 02', brand: 'cherry'}
```

I know about indexes, but they do not suit me, because I may have duplicate field values, but in different combinations.
How can this duplication be prevented?

Comment: You can create a Unique Compound Index on the fields you want to enforce uniqueness. Compound Index is an index on multiple fields together. So, when you insert a document with existing index value there will be an error / exception saying the unique index constraint is violated. Your application code need to catch this error and handle it (like tell the user that the data already exists, etc.)

Comment: @prasad_ yes I tred to use this code
carStatusSchema.createIndex( { carColor: 1, brand: 1 }, { unique: true } )
but when I use this in documents:
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'black', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'bmv'},
and try to past new document like this:
{_id: ObjectId(''), carColor: 'white', status: 'In Progress 03', brand: 'bmv'},
I get error...

Comment: Has it created the index? You can check it in mongo shell `db.collection.getIndexes()` or in the Compass GUI tool.

Comment: looks like yes, it created the index

Comment: Depending upon the fields in the compound index, you can get an error message like this (a unique index on brand+color, for example): `"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: brand_1_color_1 dup key: { brand: \"bmw\", color: \"red\" }"`

Comment: yes, I have this error